# Перенос PageFlip.as в Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, actionscript

Приветствую!
Есть класс [PageFlip](http://www.rubenswieringa.com/code/as3/flex/Book/source/source/com/foxaweb/pageflip/PageFlip.as.html), написанный на AS3, я пытаюсь его перенести на obj c.

В результате мне нужно вычисление углов листания страницы, как [здесь](http://www.rubenswieringa.com/code/as3/flex/Book/simple/).

Метод `drawRect` (аналог `computeFlip`) выглядит так:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
        CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGFloat components[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
        CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
        CGColorRelease(color);

        NSLog(@"frame -> %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
        CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);

        /*
        CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
        CGFloat angle = PSAngle(touchPoint, startPoint);
        CGPoint point1 = CGPointMake(touchPoint.x + touchPoint.x * sinf(angle), touchPoint.y + touchPoint.y * cosf(angle));
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, point1.x, point1.y);
         */
        CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(0, self.frame.size.height);

        CGFloat pw = self.frame.size.width;
        CGFloat ph = self.frame.size.height;
        CGPoint ptd=CGPointMake(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);

        //    pt1 & pt2 are the two fixed points of the sheet. opposed to ptd drag one.
        CGPoint pt1=CGPointMake(0,0);
        CGPoint pt2=CGPointMake(0,ph);
        CGPoint po = CGPointMake(1.0f, 1.0f);

        if (po.y==0)ptd.y=ph-ptd.y;
        if (po.x==0)ptd.x=pw-ptd.x;

        CGFloat dy=pt2.y-ptd.y;
        CGFloat tot=pw-ptd.x-pt1.x;
        CGFloat drx=(tot*tot-dy*dy)/(tot * 2);//(tot*tot-dy*dy)/(tot*2); // getDx(dy,tot);

        CGPoint point1 = CGPointMake(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);

        CGFloat theta = atan2f(dy, drx);
        if (dy==0)theta=0;
        CGFloat beta = M_PI/2-theta;
        CGFloat hyp = (pw-point1.x)/cosf(beta);

        CGFloat vhyp = hyp;
        if (hyp>ph || hyp<0)vhyp=ph;

        CGPoint point2= CGPointMake(point1.x+sinf(beta)*vhyp,
                                    point1.y+cosf(beta)*vhyp);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, point2.x, point2.y);

        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, point1.x, point1.y);

        CGPoint point3= CGPointMake(point1.x+drx,
                                    pt2.y);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, point3.x, point3.y);

        CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
        CGContextAddPath(context, path);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,[UIColor redColor].CGColor);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
        CGPathRelease(path);

        [super drawRect:rect];

}
```

Полный код: http://pastie.org/3388030

В итоге у меня получаются неправильные углы.
Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Вы делаете не так, т.к. пишете свою листалку, в xcode есть встроенная листалка аналогичная вашей используйте её.

Comment: нет
в xcode нет ни одной нормальной листалки ("нормальная" = аниманция как в ibooks)
пришлось всё-таки портировать листалку из actionscript`a

Comment: лучше поздно чем никогда) но нормальная встроенная системная листалка такая как в iBooks ищется по "pagecurl".